# degree_distribution vector is spaced with 0 every other number

Tags: r, igraph

I created a graph from a list of edges. Degree_distribution function returns almost correct degree distribution - every other degree is 0. If i ignore the 0's, the value is correct.

The list of edges is generated in other program of mine, where I also measured degree distribution manually. That's how I know what the answer should be.
[my edgelist](https://gist.github.com/diabeticus95/7bbb567887fbf1acb23d3528b8f438e0)

```
edgeList <- read.csv("file", h = FALSE)
mEdgeList <- as.matrix(edgeList) #graph_from_edgelist requires matrix form
mEdgeList[,] = mEdgeList[,] + 1 #my node indexes start with 0, would get rejected
graph <- graph_from_edgelist(mEdgeList, directed = F)
degree_distribution(graph, loops = F)
```

The distribution should look like:
`0.01864 0.07285 0.14704 0.19504 0.19473...`

What I get is:
`0.01794 0.00000 0.07215 0.00000 0.14738 0.00000 0.19559 0.00000...`

I am not sure whether the whole graph is created wrong, or just the degree_distribution malfunctions.
I will be very grateful for your help!

Comment: Using the csv you provided, I cannot replicate the degree distribution you share. I get: `0.01794 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.07215 0.00000 0.00000`, etc. Please print your network and share the output so we can see what it looks like in your environment.

Comment: That said, it is likely the case that you have, e.g., 0 nodes with degree 1, 0 nodes with degree 3, etc. You can check using `any(degree(graph, loops = F) == 1)`, `any(degree(graph, loops = F) == 3)`. For any degree between `0` and `max(degree(graph))` if there are no nodes in the network with that degree, `degree_distribution` returns `0`.

Comment: @paqmo
Yes, the graph I created in R does not have any nodes with every second degree - which means degree_distribution() works.  
But let me show you, that my csv data contains graph without these issues:  

`degree_dist <- edgeList %>%
    group_by(V1) %>%
    count() %>%
    group_by(n) %>%
    count()`
Which gives me:

`7215 14738 19559 19594 15843 10219  5916  2987  1327   541   181    62    14     7     2     1` degree distribution.
As to printing the graph, do you mean just print(graph)?

Comment: @paqmo
I am sorry, it seems i added the csv to the gist 2 times, which might be why you weren't able to replicate the issue - everything was doubled. I fixed the link now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. The issue was obviously on my side - I had every edge doubled, which eliminated odd degrees. Thank you for your help!